# Field name different from column name in db

Tags: node.js, graphql

I just started using graphql with mysql, i would like to know if it is possible to use a name in the graphql query different from the column name in my data base.
For example i have a table users with the columns userName and password, when i define the type for the schema i have the following:

```
const unidadesMedidaInternaType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'unidadesMedidaInterna',
    fields: () => ({
        userName: { type: GraphQLID },
        password: { type:GraphQLString }
    })
});
```

the resolver:

```
resolve (parent, args) {
    return pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users`);
}
```

so i have to query like this:

```
{
  users {
     userName,
     password
  }
}
```

i would like to have different names in the query like this:

```
{
  users {
     Name,
     secret
  }
}
```

i tried changing the names of the fields in the type definition but the result of the query is full of nulls values.

Comment: map fields in resolver

Answer (score 2):

In order to have different names in the queries you have 2 options:

**Option 1**: Use [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to run the query:
You can run your query with aliases like

```
{
  users {
     Name: userName,
     secret: password
  }
}
```

> In this case you are just renaming the fields name on execution time, so the original names will still be available to query.

**Option 2:** Map the query result to the `GraphQLObject` type.

First rename the fields:

```
const unidadesMedidaInternaType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'unidadesMedidaInterna',
    fields: () => ({
        Name: { type: GraphQLID },
        secret: { type:GraphQLString }
    })
});
```

Then map the result of the query to match the fields:

```
resolve (parent, args) {
    const result = pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users`);
    // If the result of the query is an array then you have to map its items
    return { Name: result.userName, secret: result.password }
}
```